# Testing reloading a react application

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a react page that redirects to main page if reloaded.
I want to check if the page crashed or not after reloading.
I am using react testing-library.

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Screen1/>
      <Screen2/>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

steps

- I am on screen2
- I pressed the reload button
- On reload I check for some redux value in screen2
- if the value is not available I redirect to screen1
- if the reducer is returning undefined the app crashes

now how do I check if I was redirected to Screen1 on reloading the page

Comment: It would help if you could post the code along with explanation in detail what you are  trying to achieve

Comment: added some more details , please check now

Comment: Do you want to test using a test case or what to verify it manually ?

Comment: using test case